# Errors while converting Python script to Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

I am using a Python script which uses `xmlrpclib`:

```
import xmlrpclib
srv = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://demo.myslice.info:7080/", allow_none=True)

# authentication token
auth = {"AuthMethod": "password", "Username": "guest", "AuthString": "guest"}
ret = srv.Get(auth, "slice", [["slice_hrn", '=', "ple.upmc.myslicedemo"]], {}, ["slice_hrn"])
print ret
```

I want to make a similar XML-RPC call using Ruby. For this purpose I have used the following code:

```
require "xmlrpc/client"
require "pp"

XMLRPC::Config.module_eval do
    remove_const :ENABLE_NIL_PARSER
    const_set :ENABLE_NIL_PARSER, true
end

ret = XMLRPC::Client.new2("http://demo.myslice.info:7080/")

auth = {"AuthMethod" => "password", "Username" => "guest", "AuthString" => "guest"}

pp ret.call("Get", auth, "slice", {"slice_hrn" => "ple.upmc.myslicedemo"}, ["slice_hrn"])
```

When I run this Ruby script I get the following error:

```
.../xmlrpc/client.rb:414:in `call': error (XMLRPC::FaultException)
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: full backtrace? you could also try using wireshark to look for differences in the packets produced...

Comment: @rogerdpack: this is the full error I get: /Users/rahmanm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/xmlrpc/client.rb:414:in `call': error (XMLRPC::FaultException)
 from xmlrpc.rb:17:in `<main>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error was in the conversion. Instead of list inside list, I used dictionary. I solved it:

```
require "xmlrpc/client"
require "pp"

XMLRPC::Config.module_eval do
    remove_const :ENABLE_NIL_PARSER
    const_set :ENABLE_NIL_PARSER, true
end

ret = XMLRPC::Client.new2("http://demo.myslice.info:7080/")

auth = {"AuthMethod" => "password", "Username" => "guest", "AuthString" => "guest"}

pp ret.call("Get", auth, "slice", [["slice_hrn", "=" ,"ple.upmc.myslicedemo"]], {}, ["slice_hrn"])
```