# difference between declaring object with single '@' and double '@' in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, class, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does @@variable mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890118/what-does-variable-mean-in-ruby)

What is the difference when I declare an object with double '@'

```
@@lexicon = Lexicon.new()
```

and declaring object with single '@' in Ruby?

```
@lexicon = Lexicon.new()
```

Comment: I'm not understanding why this question is being downvoted. It's a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: Me neither :(. All people are not ruby genius like them who down voted it.If this site is not for learners then they should not let us register unless we have 10 years of programming experience

Comment: @RyanBigg: If you hover over the downvote arrow you will get a tooltip which lists some of the possible legitimate reasons for downvoting. One of them is "This question does not show any research effort". Which this question doesn't: the question is answered in even the most basic beginner Ruby tutorial, and it can be answered trivially with a 3-second Google search, the first result of which is a duplicate on SO. The fact that the code snippets violate basic Ruby coding style further reinforces the appearance that the OP has not put *any* effort into answering the question himself.

Comment: @RyanBigg: Can you have a look at this problem: It's a ruby problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122615/errors-while-converting-python-script-to-ruby

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Linking to a) the google result and b) the question that is returned with a *kind* message explaining that the question has been asked before is much nicer than anonymously downvoting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that the first one is a class variable and the second one is an instance variable.

An instance variable is only available to *that instance* of an object. i.e.

```
class Yasin
  def foo=(value)
    @foo = value
  end

  def foo
    @foo
  end
end

yasin = Yasin.new
yasin.foo=1
yasin.foo #=> 1
yasin_2 = Yasin.new
yasin_2.foo #> nil
```

A class variable is available to *all* instances of the class (and subclasses, iirc) where the class variable was defined.

```
class Yasin
  def foo=(value)
    @@foo = value
  end

  def foo
    @@foo
  end
end

yasin = Yasin.new
yasin.foo=1
yasin.foo #=> 1
yasin_2 = Yasin.new
yasin_2.foo #=> 1
```

Comment: can you please elaborate with examples ? As far as i know, both of them are objects of class Lexicon right?

Comment: Your original question was "what is the difference?". I explained what the difference was.

Comment: One question: does similar thing exist in python?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. You asked a Ruby question, so I gave a Ruby answer.